# Image Uri to bytesarray

Tags: android, arrays, uri

I currently have two activities. One for pulling the image from the SD card and one for Bluetooth connection.

I have utilized a Bundle to transfer the Uri of the image from activity 1.

Now what i wish to do is get that Uri in the Bluetooth activity to and convert it into a transmittable state via Byte Arrays i have seen some examples but i can't seem to get them to work for my code!!

```
Bundle goTobluetooth = getIntent().getExtras();
    test = goTobluetooth.getString("ImageUri");
```

is what i have to pull it across. What would be the next step?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

From `Uri` to get `byte[]` I do the following things,

```
InputStream iStream =   getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
byte[] inputData = getBytes(iStream);
```

and the `getBytes(InputStream)` method is:

```
public byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
      ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      int bufferSize = 1024;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

      int len = 0;
      while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
      }
      return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }
```

Comment: getContentResolver().openInputStream(test); is receiving an error saying that it is not applicable for arguments for string!! In reference to my code above its states the the uri is in string form how do i change this to coincide with the code you have stated above!

Comment: test is a string variable you have to pass Uri. Make Uri from test and then pass it to method..

Comment: Still getting an error saying uri can't be resolved to variable!!

Comment: You have to write this line, InputStream iStream =   getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(test));

Comment: Actually instead of passing string Uri from activity 1 you have to get byte[] from it in that activity and then you have to just pass the byte[] using intent to activity 2.

Comment: i just need to now get the byte array to work within my transmission phase now. It used to send txt messages need to change it to the array just created: Thread.sleep(1000);
             OutputStream outStream;
             outStream = BT_Socket.getOutputStream();
             byte[] ByteArray = ;
                       outStream.write(ByteArray);
                       outStream.flush();
                       Thread.sleep(1500);

Comment: i just need to get the byte array into the transmission code i stated above. it keeps coming up with errors when i try and include it in byte[] ByteArray = inputdata; etc

Comment: If the above answer works for you then accept it as a correct answer and make a new question on your current problem.

Comment: this can cause an OutOfMemory error and crash at `while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) ` if the image/video/file is too large.  have a different solution?

Comment: `InputStream iStream =...` line gives me `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: @mrid just hit Alt+Enter and surround with try/catch.

Answer (score 31):

Kotlin is very concise here:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun readBytes(context: Context, uri: Uri): ByteArray? = 
    context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.use { it.buffered().readBytes() }
```

Kotlin has convenient extension functions for `InputStream` like `buffered`,`use` , and `readBytes`.

- `buffered` decorates the input stream as `BufferedInputStream`
- `use` handles closing the stream
- `readBytes` does the main job of reading the stream and writing into a byte array

Error cases:

- `IOException` can occur during the process (like in Java)
- `openInputStream` can return `null`. If you call the method in Java you can easily oversee this. Think about how you want to handle this case.

Comment: I think it's better to do `context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.use { it.buffered().readBytes() }` instead, this way you can ensure the stream is closed even if the buffer fails somehow (although improbable).

Comment: @rtsketo I agree with your suggestion. I updated the answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I am using this solution to convert a Video Uri to a ByteArray to be able to send it over a server, and but I am experiencing a memory error that says by saying something like
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 150994952 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 102MB until OOM, target footprint 118600032, growth limit 201326592

Comment: @DanielIroka This approach downloads the entire file and holds it In-Memory. This is probably not the best approach for larger video files. Consider either directly streaming the video (take a look at https://developer.android.com/media/media3/exoplayer) or saving it to disk (e.g. `use { it.buffered().copyTo(FileOutputStream("filepath")) }`)

Comment: @PeterF Thanks so much! I will look into this. I actually already make use of ExoPlayer, but I just use it for playing the video. Noob question tho, but I want to get a better understanding of something. You said to "save it to disk", what exactly is happening here? Because I already set up a FileProvider where I write the video to a file after taking it from the camera. And then it is from that file I extract the uri to convert it to a ByteArray. Or are you referring to sending the file directly to the server?? Because this is the other suggestion besides streaming it like you mentioned.

Comment: @DanielIroka Sorry, I missed the part about uploading the video. The problem still seems to be that the video is too big to be loaded into memory entirely. You could use multipart uploads in case the server supports this (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38891018/2011622).

Answer (score 9):

Syntax in kotlin

```
val inputData = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.readBytes()
```

Comment: This isn't completely correct, you need to always close `openInputStream(..)` after reading. You can use `use { }` for auto-closing it. Check Peter's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54250792/2115403).

Answer (score 5):

Java best practice: never forget to close every stream you open! 
This is my implementation:

```
/**
 * get bytes array from Uri.
 * 
 * @param context current context.
 * @param uri uri fo the file to read.
 * @return a bytes array.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static byte[] getBytes(Context context, Uri uri) throws IOException {
    InputStream iStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    try {
        return getBytes(iStream);
    } finally {
        // close the stream
        try {
            iStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) { /* do nothing */ }
    }
}



 /**
 * get bytes from input stream.
 *
 * @param inputStream inputStream.
 * @return byte array read from the inputStream.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

    byte[] bytesResult = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    try {
        int len;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        bytesResult = byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    } finally {
        // close the stream
        try{ byteBuffer.close(); } catch (IOException ignored){ /* do nothing */ }
    }
    return bytesResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri) to get an InputStream from a URI. and then read the data from inputstream convert the data into byte[] from that inputstream

Try with following code

```
public byte[] readBytes(Uri uri) throws IOException {
          // this dynamically extends to take the bytes you read
        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
          ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

          // this is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes
          int bufferSize = 1024;
          byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

          // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer
          int len = 0;
          while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
          }

          // and then we can return your byte array.
          return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
        }
```

Refer this LINKs

Comment: Whats the difference between your answer and mine?

Comment: The name of method :)

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

```
Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                 bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                 .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void uriToByteArray(String uri)
    {

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File(uri));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n;
        try {
            while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
                baos.write(buf, 0, n);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method to create a `bytesArray` from a `URI` in Android studio.

```
public byte[] getBytesArrayFromURI(Uri uri) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d("exception", "Oops! Something went wrong.");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that ***closes byte streams*** and takes care of your memory:

---

```
fun Uri.readBytes(context: Context): ByteArray? {
    var inputStream          : InputStream? = null
    var byteArrayOutputStream: ByteArrayOutputStream? = null

    try {
        inputStream           = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(this)
        byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()

        if (inputStream != null) {
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var bytesRead: Int

            while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
            }

            return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        inputStream?.close()
        byteArrayOutputStream?.close()
    }

    return null
}
```