# Android, parse, storing image file from camera

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to store an image file in Parse.com for use as a profile photo.

I have a function used to capture the image:

```
private void captureImage() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);



            // start the image capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
```

According to Parse [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#files), I need to have the data in byte[] form and then create a ParseFile with it.  So, I have this:

```
            byte[] data = fileUri.getBytes();

            // Save image to Parse
            photoFile = new ParseFile("profile_photo.jpg", data);
```

I am getting an error: cannot resolve method getBytes.  Not entirely sure if I am missing an import, or if I am approaching this the entirely wrong way.  How can I convert a captured image file to byte form so I can create a ParseFile?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039672/android-how-to-read-file-in-bytes

Comment: You can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296734/image-uri-to-bytesarray