# Getting half image when convert bitmap to base64

Tags: android, image, bitmap, base64, encode

I want to upload image to server which is accept images in base64 encored format. I use this code to encode bitmap, But it encode only half of the image and server receive only half of the image part.

This is my code.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();

            String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
// Send to server(encoded)
```

and when I try to encode image from gallery it pop up a error and crashes the app, with error.

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 15521174 byte allocation with 13777320 free bytes and 13MB until OOM

I want to encode the full image, any help?

Comment: Send it as a stream. Rather than storing it in a byte array. As you are running out of memory.

Comment: search on google `OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: @KZoNE try my answer

Comment: send it through multipart. best way to upload image

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Doomsknight, Error pop up before it send, When I try to set encored string? Any idea?

Comment: I tried it @IntelliJAmiya, But unable to find proper solution,

Comment: @DaminiMehra will check,  thanks

Comment: @TanveerBulsari do you have any example?

Comment: use a [Base64Stream](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64OutputStream.html). Set the file to stream and send that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562950/post-multipart-form-data-using-retrofit-2-0-including-image

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

check this both link out. It will for sure give you a clear idea.

Comment: Thanks @TanveerBulsari, What will receive at the backend with the retrofit request? Is it a base64 encoded string?

Comment: it would be a multipart form value, if it is an image you have get it as a multipart file and write that file it on the server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options;
 options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
    // images
    options.inSampleSize = 6;
   Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri1.getPath(),
                        options);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                if(bitmap1 != null) {
                    bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, baos1);
                    byte[] b1 = baos1.toByteArray();
                    bitmapstring1 = Base64.encodeToString(b1,    

                   Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I feel this will lower the quality of the image. Actually I don't want to make it low quality? Do you know any code to send with out lowering the quality?

I mean, I think better to use bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos1);
What do you think?

Comment: use it bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos1);  no problem occured @KZoNE

Answer (score 1):

you must be getting 'OutOfMemoryError' because may be you are using an image of very high resolution and loading it directly into the memory, and hence the String for base64 is too large. Always load a sub sampled version of the image in memory to avoid `OutOfMemoryError`. [Take a look at this.](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) 
From the docs:

> For example, it’s not worth loading a 1024x768 pixel image into memory if it will eventually be displayed in a 128x96 pixel thumbnail in an ImageView.

First calculate the sample size for the image:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

return inSampleSize;
}
```

Then decode the sampled version :

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

// First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

After the sampled version of the bitmap is loaded, then convert the bitmap to base64.

Comment: i already user your sample but still have a white half image . Do you know why that happened?

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.d(TAG, "getStringImage: "+encodedImage.trim());
    return encodedImage;
}
```

try this

Comment: How is this answer different to the code he posted, (apart from less compression)

Comment: I mean the code in the question. :) The other answer is different

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, But this is the issue that I want to solve