# How to upload image in object using retrofit in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit2

I am trying to update my profile information. I am using `retrofit2`. When I didn't add photo in our object then I am able to update data on server using `retrofit`. for example

```
@POST("users/{id}/") 
Call<ServiceResponse> calledEditProfile(@Header("Authorization") String token,
                                                @Path("id") String id,
                                                @Part JsonObject jsonObject);
```

I am using this type object for updating the data.

```
{
  "user": {
            "fullname": "Ashutosh",
            "username": "ashu",
            "email": "ashu@gmail.com",
            "photo: ""
        }
}
```

and it is working fine but when I tried to upload image using `multipart` then it is not supporting.
I have Googled many thing but didn't get satisfactory answer.

I have tried `@part` but didn't get success.

Please suggest me how can I move forward from here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: well read this maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562950/post-multipart-form-data-using-retrofit-2-0-including-image