# Uploading a photo and send it via RestApi

Tags: android

[image]

I got this endpoint but i don't know how to take photo from phone gallery and send this image via this endpoint?

Comment: check this tutorial https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server, which helps you to send files to server using Retrofit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008840/how-to-use-retrofit-2-to-send-file-and-other-params-together

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

add below depedency into app level gradle file..

```
   implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

then define retrofit object..

```
public class ApiClient {
private final static String BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com";

public static ApiClient apiClient;
private Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static ApiClient getInstance() {
    if (apiClient == null) {
        apiClient = new ApiClient();
    }
    return apiClient;
}

//private static Retrofit storeRetrofit = null;

public Retrofit getClient() {
    return getClient(null);
}


private Retrofit getClient(final Context context) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    return retrofit;
}
}
```

make api interface..

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@Multipart
@POST("/signup/")
Call<UserResponseVo> registerUser(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> map);
}
```

and api calling into actiivty..

```
 private void uploadImage() {
    ApiInterface apiInterface= ApiClient.getInstance().getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    file=new File(mAttachmentFilePath);
    RequestBody mFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("profile_pic", file.getName(), mFile);
    RequestBody userObjectId = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text"), "HZucg1m6Gz");



    Call<UserProfileResponse> userProfileResponseCall=apiInterface.uploadImage(fileToUpload,userObjectId);
    showProgress();
    userProfileResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<UserProfileResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserProfileResponse> call, Response<UserProfileResponse> response) {
            if (response!=null && response.body()!=null && response.isSuccessful()){
                closeProgress();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.body().getMsg(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("Response Message::",response.body().getMsg());
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(response.body().getAvatarUrl()).into(mIvServerImage);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserProfileResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            closeProgress();
            Log.d("Error::",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

and i hope you know how to open gallery and get selected image path.
and if you run app above marshallow device then add permission model.