# Android Retrofit 2 multipart always giving error 400

Tags: android, image, flask, retrofit, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send one image and somes string through retrofit, but it's not working, I'm always getting a 400. My app is already using webservices such as GET or POST without troubles, I assume that my probleme is with the upload...

I used that [explanations](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server) and the github of retrofit.

My idea here is to create a new Dish and sed it to my server, so most of the data are comming from InputTextField and the photo is taken by the camera using an Intent

**First my interface for uploading**

```
@Multipart
@POST("japronto/api/chef/dish/new")
Call<Dish> upload(@Part("name") RequestBody name, @Part("description") RequestBody description,@Part("disponibility") RequestBody disp,@Part("max") RequestBody max,@Part("price") RequestBody price, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

**My function to upload**

```
    public void onOK(){

    RequestBody name = RequestBody.create( MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), this.name.getText().toString());
    RequestBody description =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), this.description.getText().toString());
    RequestBody disp =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), Integer.toString(this.TorF));

    RequestBody max =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), this.max.getText().toString());

    RequestBody price =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), this.price.getText().toString());


    File nImg = new File(folderImg, imgName);

    RequestBody rqFile =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), nImg);

    MultipartBody.Part body =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", nImg.getName(), rqFile);

    ApiService apiService = ApiManager.createService(ApiService.class, this.chef.getPseudo(), this.chef.getPassword());
    Call<Dish> call = apiService.upload(name, description, disp, max, price, body);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Dish>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Dish> call, Response<Dish> response) {
            Dish d = response.body();
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+d.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Dish> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}
```

**My view on the server**

```
    @app.route('/japronto/api/chef/dish/new', methods=['POST'])
    def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
     if 'file' not in request.files:
        print 'pbs'
    file = request.files['file']

    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        print filename
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return {'name':filename}
return{'name':'erro'}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Multipart
@POST("japronto/api/chef/dish/new")
Call<Dish> upload(@Part("name") RequestBody name, @Part("description") RequestBody description,@Part("disponibility") RequestBody disp,@Part("max") RequestBody max,@Part("price") RequestBody price, @Part("ImageNameHere\"; filename=\"image.png\" ") RequestBody image);



File nImg = new File(folderImg, imgName);
RequestBody rqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), nImg);
```

check these links

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562950/post-multipart-form-data-using-retrofit-2-0-including-image) [Link 2](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap) [Link 3](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-multiple-files-to-server)

Comment: There is some progress, now my server is giving an error 400 and I still can't get the image doing an 

        `file = request.files['file'] ` (using Flask)

Comment: try hitting same url with postman and see if problem is from server code or app code

Comment: Already tried and I´ve got no error...
I can´t test right now, but I think that the probleme is in the header of the packet.