# Retrofit Multipart with Body

Tags: android, retrofit2

This is how the `body` for the call should look like (image field will be added).

`{

   "email":"test",
   "username":"test",
   "password":"test",
   "name":"test",
   "description":"Something...",
   "OAuthCredentialsTest":{

      "client_id":23,
      "client_secret":"test"
   }
}`

I am using `@PartMap` as the `body` in my call:

```
Call<CreateUserResult> createUserPart(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> map);
```

And then when I `enqueue` the call:

```
File file = new File(signUpUser.getImagePath());
    RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    RequestBody fullName = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), signUpUser.getFullName());
    RequestBody email = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), signUpUser.getEmail());
    RequestBody username = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), signUpUser.getUsername());
    RequestBody password = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), signUpUser.getPassword());
    RequestBody desc = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), signUpUser.getDescription());

    Map<String, RequestBody> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put("file\"; filename=\"" + file.getName(), fileBody);
    myMap.put("name", fullName);
    myMap.put("email", email);
    myMap.put("username", username);
    myMap.put("password", password);
    myMap.put("description", desc);
```

But, how can I include the `OAuthCredentialsTest` key and values part in my `myMap`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.