# Retrofit - Spring Image upload

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-mvc, retrofit

I have a problem in uploading file to server(Spring Boot) from Android-retrofit.

this is my code in Spring Boot.

```js
@RestController
@RequestMapping("beongae/api/{version}/profile")
public class ProfileController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload/{name}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ApiMessasge uploadBasic(@PathVariable("name") String name,
                                   @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile data) throws IOException {
        ApiMessasge apiMessasge = new ApiMessasge();
        System.out.println("start upload !!");
        if (!data.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = data.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream("./profilepictures/" + new File(name + ".png"))
                );
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                apiMessasge.setCode(1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
                for (int i = 0; i < e.getStackTrace().length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(e.getStackTrace()[i].toString());
                }
                apiMessasge.setCode(-1);
            }
        }
        return apiMessasge;
    }
}
```

This is in Android

```js
Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
File file = new File(resultUri.getPath());

RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestFile);
```

And this is in APiService.class

```js
@Multipart
@Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
@POST("/beongae/api/{version}/profile/upload/{name}")
Call<ApiMessasge> upload(@Path("version") int version, @Path("name") String fileName
        , @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

And This is the error message in Spring Boot

> 2017-09-19 21:34:51.179 ERROR 22271 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request
>   is not a multipart request] with root cause
>       org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.java:151)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_131]
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_131]
>               at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]

But, It's done well when I use Postman.

Please tell me what is the problem and how to solve

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sYO7.png]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST Multipart Form Data using Retrofit 2.0 including image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562950/post-multipart-form-data-using-retrofit-2-0-including-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your service a little bit and try

```
 @Part("file\"; filename=\"filename.png\" ")
```