# how to upload Image as multipart/form-data from android to Nodejs (gridfs is the way i am storing images)

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, express, gridfs

I planned to use volley library to solve this. there are some `org.apache.http` library (which is deprecated i think). but i want to build my app on latest buld.

i am saving images using gridfs,
ie;

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.keepExtensions = true;     //keep file extension

    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {

var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
                        filename: fields.temp_name,
                        mode: 'w',
                        content_type: 'image/png'
                    });
                    fs.createReadStream(files.template.path).pipe(writestream);


                    writestream.on('close', function (file) {
                        // do something with `file`
                        console.log(file.filename + ' Written To DB');
                        if(err){
                            res.send("error")
                        }else{
                            // do whatever you want
                            console.log("Upload Session name: "+"upload_complete"+req.session.username);
                            io.emit("upload_complete"+req.session.username, "File Uploaded Successfully");
                            //io.emit("upload_complete", "File Uploaded Successfully");
                        }
                    });

            }else{
                io.emit("upload_error"+req.session.username, "Duplicate Name");
            }
```

on webside (browser-server) i first save image to temp directory on server then i write into mongodb using gridfs. (i dont know if this is the correct way!)

**how to upload images from android? `volley` is better ? or which is the best way to do this?** 
can you provide a good guide to do this? or please share some code..

Answer (score 1):

I've had success working with Retrofit2 - https://square.github.io/retrofit/ | https://github.com/square/retrofit

You can use the code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38891018/4455570

When you're uploading an image you make a request as so:

> ```
> @Multipart
> @POST("uploadAttachment")
> Call<MyResponse> uploadAttachment(@Part MultipartBody.Part filePart); 
>                                // You can add other parameters too
> ```

And then you attach the image to the request as so:

> ```
> File file = // initialize file here
>
> MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", 
> file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file));
>
> Call<MyResponse> call = api.uploadAttachment(filePart);
> ```

In Node.js / Express.js you can accept the incoming image using multer: https://github.com/expressjs/multer

In your route you can pre-process the image using the example below:

```
app.post('/uploadAttachment', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
// req.file is the `avatar` file
// req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

where "image" is the name of the file I believe. I hope this helps!