# How can volley handle multipart request? Is it efficient? Which other libraries are best suited for sending and receiving big files?

Tags: android, request, android-volley, multipart

I am using volley currently to send and get a normal text from the server. Can volley be used to send and receive multipart data to the server ??  Is it efficient? Which alternative library do you suggest to send receive multipart data from server?

Can we send any multipart data ( for ex. ppt,docs,pdf,text) using retrofit.
Any suggestion is extremely appreciated....

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest retrofit which is easy way to implement multipart and very efficient also

You can send Multiple files using MultipartBuilder

https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/MultipartBuilder.html

for more info
[POST Multipart Form Data using Retrofit 2.0 including image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562950/post-multipart-form-data-using-retrofit-2-0-including-image)