# does @Multipart (Annotation) Supports @Query in android Retrofit 2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I need to know that retrofit 2 supports `@Multipart` annotation with`@Query` like this

```
@Multipart
    @POST("media/upload_media")
    Call<ResponseBody> upload(
        @Part MultipartBody.Part media,
        @Query("user-id") int user_id ,
        @Query("type") String type
     );
```

I am using this in my application and I am not getting a successful response.

Comment: _"I am not getting a successful response."_ then what's response? Please [edit] the question and post error log if there any.

Comment: i just want to kow that is it support @Querry ?

Comment: i just need to know that is it possible to add multiple parameters like @Querry with the Multipart annotation ?/?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. If I understood your requirements, [@Part](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap) or `@PartMap` is what you're trying to use.

Comment: can you write a sample cod for me

Comment: if i tell you my parameters can you help me with a sample code to upload image??\ @Shashanth

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50310161/5180017) StackOverflow answer. You'll get an idea about uploading file with description. You simply need to use `@Part` annotation with `RequestBody` type instead of `String` or `int`.