# post file with java rest web service

Tags: java, android, rest, web-services, retrofit2

I'm setting up a new payara server
i want to upload a file from a my application to the server 
I have created a java rest web service and  i have send Some objects have been successfully received using retrofit 2
Now I want to send a file from my phone to the server
I don't   know how to write a post method in the   java  web service to receive a file

this is  the interface definition for file uploads using retrofit 2

```
public interface FileUploadService {  
    @Multipart
    @POST("upload")
    Call<ResponseBody> upload(
        @Part("description") RequestBody description,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part file
    );
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562950/post-multipart-form-data-using-retrofit-2-0-including-image