# 'stream ended unexpectedly' error while Multipart Image Upload using Retrofit 2.0 - Android

Tags: android, retrofit, multipartform-data

I am using Retrofit 2.0 for image upload to server in Android. Following is the interface code.

```
    @Headers("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=MyMediaFormBoundary")
@Multipart
@POST("api/media/upload/v1")
Call<MyResponse> uploadMedia(@Header("authToken") String authToken,
                                      @Part("media_file\"; filename=\"media_file.jpg\" ") RequestBody filePart,
                                      @Part("media_format") RequestBody format,
                                      @Part("media_library_id") RequestBody noteId,
                                      @Part("media_title") RequestBody title);
```

Here is my code to create request body params

```
File file = new File(mediaFileUri.getPath());
                RequestBody fbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
                RequestBody formatBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), format);
                RequestBody titleBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), title);
                RequestBody idBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), id + "");
```

When I call my interface method with above parameters, I am getting error 'steam ended unexpectedly' and I am wondering what exactly I am doing wrong.

I also tried using MultipartBody.Part object of retrofit in above interface but still same result.

Following are the links which I used for reference:
[first link](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1063)
[second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562950/post-multipart-form-data-using-retrofit-2-0-including-image)

Note: I doubt it is related to bad request but I am not getting much help from backend team and it is working on iOS. The only info I have is server side is fetching media file against key 'media_file' but I am wondering where to use it.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve the issue or find the culprit?

Answer (score -1):

If you are sending image then why the media type is text/plain?

Comment: This is not the answer. This can be added as comment to question.

Second thing: For media file, media type is 'image/*' and for other parameters it is 'text/plain'. Please recheck.