# How to send File of any type in post parameter in Retrofit 2 Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, multipart

Let me share some of my code which i have implemented to send image file in the request.

Below is my function of api request:

```
@Multipart
@POST("api/order/order_create")
fun createOrder(
    @Header("Authorization") authorization: String?,
    @Part("category_id") categoryId: RequestBody?,
    @Part("size") size: RequestBody?,
    @Part("narration") narration: RequestBody?,
    @Part("ref_picture") file: RequestBody?
): Call<OrderCreateResponse>
```

Below is the code where i am calling the api by sending the necessary parameters:

```
var fbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), imageFile)
var size = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), et_custom_order_size.text.toString())
var catId = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), selectedID.toString())
var narration = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),et_custom_order_narration.text.toString())

val orderCreateAPI = apiService!!.createOrder(complexPreferences?.getPref("token", null), catId,size,narration,fbody)
```

Here imageFile is fetched by the below way,

```
imageFile = File(Global.getRealPathFromURI(activity!!, imageUri!!))
```

Using below function to get the real path,

```
fun getRealPathFromURI(context: Context, contentUri: Uri): String {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        try {
            val proj = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
            cursor = context.contentResolver.query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null)
            val column_index = cursor!!.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            return cursor.getString(column_index)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getRealPathFromURI Exception : " + e.toString())
            return ""
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close()
            }
        }
    }
```

By sending image in the above way, i am not able to send it! Please guide me with the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to send image to server then you should use _MultipartBody.Part_

Comment: What are you getting in Global.getRealPathFromURI(activity!!, imageUri!!) method

Comment: Make sure check your file should not getting null.

Comment: @MayurPatel Yes sir i have checked the condition for null case!

Comment: @hetsgandhi First of all I am not sir, And can you pls share your code of getRealPathFromURI method too

Comment: Yes i have added the function, please refer it! @MayurPatel

Comment: @Piyush i also tried using that, but its not working!

Comment: Same error are you getting?

Comment: Yes sir @Piyush

Comment: Have you tried with Postman? Does it work or not?

Comment: Yes it works with RestClient and checked with iOS too! @Piyush

Comment: Are you able to get proper path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194733/discussion-between-piyush-and-hetsgandhi).

Answer (score 3):

```
@Multipart
@POST("register")
Observable<SignInResponse> signUp(@Part("name") RequestBody name, @Part MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload);
```

Then pass image file as MultipartBody.Part variable

```
// image as file
    var body: MultipartBody.Part? = null
    if (!profileImagePath.isNullOrBlank()) {
        val file = File(profileImagePath)
        val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(file))
        val requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), getBytes(inputStream))
        body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.name, requestFile)
        Log.d("nama file e cuk", file.name)
    }
```

Last thing you can make RequestBody var

```
RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), user_full_name)
```

finally send request :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 
`@Part("ref_picture") file: RequestBody?` 
to
`@Part("ref_picture") file: MultipartBody.Part?`

And do this

```
// create RequestBody instance from file
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)),file);

// MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);
```

You may also check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34562971/8401371

Comment: Do you know what is Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this way :

```
    var propertyImagePart: MultipartBody.Part? = null
            imageUrl.value?.let {
                val propertyImageFile = File(FILE_PATH)
                val propertyImage: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), propertyImageFile)
                propertyImagePart =MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("userImage", propertyImageFile.name, propertyImage)
            }

    job = launch {
            try {
                val response = apiServiceWithoutHeader.doUpdateProfile(propertyImagePart,profileRequest.getMultipart()).await()
                stateLiveData.postValue(UserProfileState.SuccessUpdateProfile(response))
            } catch (e: JsonSyntaxException) {
                onException(e)
            } catch (e: JsonParseException) {
                onException(e)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                onException(e)
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                onException(e)
            }
        }
```