# Unable to upload image from android

Tags: php, android, file, bitmap, retrofit

I am trying to register user details like(nam, number, email, password and image). I have already written API in php and it's working fine if I post it from postman.

Here is postman screenshot :
[image]

But when I tried to send data from android then I am getting error message from server like "`Required parameters (name, email or password) is missing!`". It's working when i post from postman but not from my android code. I am surely doing something wrong.
Here is php api :

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization');
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("status" => 1);

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['number']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset( $_FILES[ 'image' ]) && isset($_POST['pns_token']) && isset($_POST['is_owner']) && isset($_POST['tbl_flat_id']) && isset($_POST['tbl_building_id']) && isset($_POST['tbl_society_id'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $pns_token = $_POST['pns_token'];
    $is_owner = $_POST['is_owner'];
    $tbl_flat_id = $_POST['tbl_flat_id'];
    $tbl_building_id = $_POST['tbl_building_id'];
    $tbl_society_id = $_POST['tbl_society_id'];


    //$guest_master = $db -> storeGuest($name, $number, $email, $password, $image);


    // check if user is already existed with the same email
    if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
        // user already existed
        $response["status"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "User already existed with " . $email;
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // create a new user
        $user = $db->storeUser($name, $number, $email, $password, $image, $pns_token, $is_owner, $tbl_flat_id, $tbl_building_id, $tbl_society_id);
        if ($user) {
             return result
            $response["status"] = 0;
            $response["id"] = intval($user["userId"]);
            $response["message"] = "User registered successfully with " . $email;
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["status"] = 2;
            $response["message"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
} else {
    // receiving the post params
    $response["status"] = 3;
    $response["message"] = "Required parameters (name, email or password) is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Here is my android code  :
NetworkService.java  :

```
public interface NetworkService {
// retrofit get call
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(Constants.USER_LOGIN)
Call<UserLoginResponse> executeLogin(@Field("email") String email,
                                     @Field("password") String password);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(Constants.USER_REGISTER)
Call<UserRegistrationResponse> executeRegistration(@Field("name") String name,
                                                   @Field("number") String number,
                                                   @Field("email") String email,
                                                   @Field("password") String password,
                                                   @Field("image") File imagePath,
                                                   @Field("pns_token") String pnsToken,
                                                   @Field("is_owner") int isOwner,
                                                   @Field("tbl_flat_id") int flatId,
                                                   @Field("tbl_building_id") int buildingId,
                                                   @Field("tbl_society_id") int societyId
                                                   );
}
```

Here is my RegisterActivity.java .   :

```
NetworkService networkService = 
App.getClient(EXTENDED_URL).create(NetworkService.class);
Call<UserRegistrationResponse> call = 
networkService.executeRegistration(txtName.getText().toString(),
                            txtNumber.getText().toString(),
                            txtEmail.getText().toString(),
                            txtPassword.getText().toString(),
                            imagePath,
                            pnsToken,
                            0,
                            flatId,
                            buildingId,
                            societyId
                            );
```

Here is code which converting image to file in RegsiterActivity  :

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imvPhoto.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

        imagePath = savebitmap("profile_photo", imageBitmap);
    }
}

private File savebitmap(String filename, Bitmap imageBitmap) {
    File filesDir = getFilesDir();
    File imageFile = new File(filesDir, filename + ".jpg");

    OutputStream os;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error writing bitmap", e);
    }
    return imageFile;

}
```

Please provide my any reference or help so I can resolve this.

Comment: did you try to log all of your POST array? so you can see which parameter is missing

Comment: yes I logged it already, Parameters are not missing

Comment: are you sure noone parameter is missing? not just those 3, but noone.

Comment: Yes, I just debug it twice and I am not missing any parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use multipart on this.

There's a similar answer provided in the link below that tells you how to upload image with other data, you can check it out.

[POST Multipart Form Data using Retrofit 2.0 including image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562950/post-multipart-form-data-using-retrofit-2-0-including-image)