# How to add image in api call using retrofit and other body items as well?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

first, of all i tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34562971/14599955) question but it doesn't works.

I have to call an API and send an image and a user name in the body, i do have called the APIs before using the retrofit but i have no idea how to send an image now.

here is my code as of now

```
private fun uploadProfileToDashboard(path: String) {
    var aes = Utils.getPref(
        requireContext(),
        Constants.ENCRYPTION_AES,
        "x"
    )!!
    var iv = Utils.getPref(
        requireContext(),
        Constants.ENCRYPTION_IV,
        "x"
    )!!

    val file: File = File(path)

    val fbody = RequestBody.create(
        "image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull(),
        file
    )

    profileViewModel.updateProfilePicInDashboard(
        mapOf(
            "object_id" to Utils.getPref(
                requireContext(),
                Constants.ENCRYPTION_OBJ_ID,
                "x"
            )!!,
            "db_name" to Utils.getPref(
                requireContext(),
                Constants.PROVIDER_NAME,
                "x"
            )!!
        ),
        AESEncryption(
            aes,
            iv
        ).encrypt(profile.dashboardUserName)!!,
        fbody

    )

}


fun updateProfilePicInDashboard(
    headerParams: Map<String, String>,
    user_id: String,
    image: RequestBody
) {
    val call = RetrofitClient.updateProfilePicInDashboard.updateProfilePic(headerParams , user_id , image)
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<UserProfilePicResponceModal> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<UserProfilePicResponceModal>,
            response: Response<UserProfilePicResponceModal>
        ) {
            Log.i("here22" , response.body().toString())
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserProfilePicResponceModal>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.i("here22" , t.message.toString())
        }

    })
}



   @Multipart
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/index.php/Profile/editProfile")
    fun updateProfilePic(
        @HeaderMap headers: Map<String, String>,
        @Part("user_id") userId: String,
        @Part("file\"; filename=\"pp.png\" ") userfile: RequestBody
    ) : Call<UserProfilePicResponceModal>
```

But this does work, it fire an error -> Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=67940, result=-1, data=Intent

Answer (score 1):

you can use **RequestBody** for sending images and data to API.

For Ex:

Java

```
@POST("End_point_of_api")
    Call<Response> doUpdateProfileDetails(
            @Body RequestBody requestBody
    );
```

kotlin

```
@POST("End_point_of_api")
    fun doUpdateProfileDetails(
        @Body RequestBody requestBody
    ) : Call<Response>
```

And call above API as follow:

Java

```
MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
        
    builder.addFormDataPart("userName", "user123");
    builder.addFormDataPart("userPhoto", "file_name", RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, new File("path")));
        
    RequestBody requestBody = builder.build();
        
    // call api here and pass requestBody as a parameter.
```

kotlin

```
val builder = MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)

        builder.addFormDataPart("userName", "user123")
        builder.addFormDataPart("userPhoto", "file_name", RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, File("path")))

        val requestBody: RequestBody = builder.build()

        // call api here and pass requestBody as a parameter.
```