# Uploading multiple types of file to parse database using uri i/o error

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-server, back4app

I have an app that uses Parse-Server as a backend, which I am using through back4app. The database that parse-server is supplying is the database of my app.

I am following the following docs
https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#files

My app has multiple upload file buttons in a fragment. My app takes in .pdf, image files and .doc files. However, when I try to save the newly created parse files using saveDataInBackground(), I am getting i/o error.

My code as below:

In my fragment, I am retrieving using onActivityResult

```
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    binding.cross1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    String uriString = uri.toString();
                    File myFile = new File(uriString);

                    parseFiles[0] = (new ParseFile(myFile));

                    String displayName = null;

                    if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                        Cursor cursor = null;
                        try {
                            cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            }
                        } finally {
                            cursor.close();
                        }
                    } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                        displayName = myFile.getName();
                    }

                    binding.file1.setText(displayName);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    binding.cross2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    String uriString = uri.toString();
                    File myFile = new File(uriString);

                    parseFiles[1] = (new ParseFile(myFile));

                    String displayName = null;

                    if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                        Cursor cursor = null;
                        try {
                            cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            }
                        } finally {
                            cursor.close();
                        }
                    } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                        displayName = myFile.getName();
                    }

                    binding.file2.setText(displayName);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    binding.cross3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    String uriString = uri.toString();
                    File myFile = new File(uriString);

                    parseFiles[2] = (new ParseFile(myFile));

                    String displayName = null;

                    if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                        Cursor cursor = null;
                        try {
                            cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            }
                        } finally {
                            cursor.close();
                        }
                    } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                        displayName = myFile.getName();
                    }

                    binding.file3.setText(displayName);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

And in my activity, I am attempting to save the parseFiles as such.

```
 ArrayList<ParseFile> parseFiles = new ArrayList<>();


            for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getFragmentJobSample().getParseFiles().length; i++) {
                if (adapter.getFragmentJobSample().getParseFiles()[i] != null){
                    parseFiles.add(adapter.getFragmentJobSample().getParseFiles()[i]);
                }
            }


            entity.put("fileOne", parseFiles.get(0));
            entity.put("fileTwo", parseFiles.get(1));
            entity.put("fileThree", parseFiles.get(2));

            for (int i = 0; i < parseFiles.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    parseFiles.get(i).save();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "e" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            // Saves the new object.
            // Notice that the SaveCallback is totally optional!
            entity.saveInBackground(e -> {
                if (e == null) {
               

 //Save was done
                Toast.makeText(this, "success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            } else {
                //Something went wrong
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

I had to use .save() because I need to save multiple files at once. I thought that using .saveInBackground() would not be wise for this. Should I have used .saveInBackground() instead?

Comment: `However, when I try to save the newly created parse files ..` What is a parse file? And suddenly you are saving. Ok. But then why are you talking about uploading in the subject?

Comment: `File myFile = new File(uriString);` It makes no sense to use the File class on your nice uri. Have a look at the value of `uriSting`. Please tell.

Comment: I have edited my question for better clarity

Comment: I have no idea what you have done. You better had done what i asked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it into byte array first. To do so please have a look at this link below:
[Image Uri to bytesarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296734/image-uri-to-bytesarray)

After that simply associate it with your file like this:

```
byte[] data = "Working at Parse is great!".getBytes();
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("resume.txt", data);
```

Then try saving this file, it should work.

Comment: This works perfectly, however can you tell me why it does not work when I initialize a parseFile using new ParseFile(new File(uriString)) ?

Comment: https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/master/Parse.File.html
Maybe the parameters have to be in the same sequence?
For example first name, then data. I'm not sure though, so have to check

Comment: But in any case, it's always best to follow the official doc for the specific SDK