# Permission denied while accessing file Android 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio, chaquopy

I am accessing text file in android but the permission denied errno13 showed up and i have already given all permission of storage

This is the logcat error which showing
[image: This is the logcat error which showing]

Application permission code
[image: Application permission code]

Comment: Do you target Android 11?  Android no longer permit access to external storage, unless you're developing a file manager. If it's for educational purposes, you can declare All Files Access permission (be a file manager)

Comment: and this permission is already declared (`MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`), but is it granted? @op check in system settings of your app

Comment: Declaring permissions in manifest was the old way. Those permissions might also need to be asked at runtime as [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) in modern Android versions.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Chaquopy FAQ](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/faq.html#read-files-from-external-storage-sdcard):

Since API level 29, Android has a [scoped storage policy](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage) which prevents direct access to external storage, even if your app has the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Instead, you can use the [system file picker](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#open-document), and pass the file to Python as a byte array:

```kotlin
val REQUEST_OPEN = 0

fun myMethod() {
    startActivityForResult(
        Intent(if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
               else Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).apply {
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            setType("*/*")
        }, REQUEST_OPEN)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_OPEN && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val uri = data!!.data!!
        // For Java, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10297073
        val content = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)!!.use { it.readBytes() }
        myPythonModule.callAttr("process", content)
    }
}
```

The Python function can then access the file content however you like:

```py
def process(content):
    # `content` is already a bytes-like object, but if you need a standard bytes object:
    content = bytes(content)

    # If you need a file-like object:
    import io
    content_file = io.BytesIO(content)

    # If you need a filename (less efficient):
    import tempfile
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp_file:
        temp_file.write(content)
        filename = temp_file.name  # Valid only inside the `with` block.
```

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use below permissions if just want to access videos and images :

"android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"
"android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"

instead of using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: The question is about accessing a text file.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to obtaining these permissions (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)during the initial run of the program, you must add the following code to the AndroidManifest.xml file in  tag.

```
  android: requestLegacyExternalStorage = "true"
```

Comment: Google changes their privacy policy's since 1st of May 2021. After this Google Play Store will not accept this '(android: requestLegacyExternalStorage = "true")'.

Comment: This flag no is ignored if app targets Android 11