# 'Is poppler installed and in PATH' - Running pdf2Image script in android

Tags: python, android, android-studio, chaquopy, pdf2image

I have a custom python script using pdf2Image which I am trying to run on an android phone. I have  tried these two ways

1. Use an android app that can run python scripts on android.
2. Create an android app and integrate my python code (using [chaquopy](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html)).

But in both the cases, I am getting

`W/System.err: com.chaquo.python.PyException: PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?`

My scripts are running seamlessly on ubuntu terminal (using `python <scriptFileName.py>`) but when I try to do it on android, it is giving me the above issue

My trouble is that I am not able to understand how can I install poppler, or add it to PATH in android.

Following is my script that converts the PDF into JPEG images (Module name = pdf2Img.py):

```py
from pdf2image import convert_from_bytes
import sys
import os
import shutil
import io

def extractImagesFromPdf(fileContents):

    BASE_DIR = 'in_pdfs'
    EXTENSION = '.pdf'
    OUT_DIR = 'images'
    IMG_EXT = '.jpg'
    sep = "/"

    if not os.path.exists(getDirectoryPath(BASE_DIR)):
        os.mkdir(getDirectoryPath(BASE_DIR))

    pages = convert_from_bytes(fileContents)

    if os.path.exists(getDirectoryPath(OUT_DIR)):
        shutil.rmtree(getDirectoryPath(OUT_DIR))
        os.mkdir(getDirectoryPath(OUT_DIR))

    page_num = 1
    for page in pages:
        page.save(getDirectoryPath(OUT_DIR) + sep + str(page_num) + IMG_EXT, 'JPEG')
        page_num = page_num + 1

def getDirectoryPath(dir):
    base_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return base_path + "/" + dir
```

This is how I am invoking it

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PICK_PDF_FILE = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void selectAndUploadFile(View view) {
        Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");

        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PDF_FILE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
        if (requestCode == PICK_PDF_FILE
                && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri inPDF = null;
            if (resultData != null) {
                inPDF = resultData.getData();
                Log.i("SelectAndUpload", "onActivityResult: " + inPDF);

                if (!Python.isStarted()) {
                    Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(MainActivity.this));
                }

                Python py = Python.getInstance();
                PyObject module = py.getModule("pdf2Img");

                try {
                    InputStream iStream =   getContentResolver().openInputStream(inPDF);
                    byte[] inputData = getBytes(iStream);
                    PyObject result = module.callAttr("extractImagesFromPDF", inputData);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("Ex", "Exception!!!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

And the error is coming at line

```
    pages = convert_from_path(BASE_DIR + sep + fileName + EXTENSION)
```

Few references:

1. [Chaquopy getting started documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html)
2. [Converting uri to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296734/image-uri-to-bytesarray/10297073#10297073)
3. [pdf2Image (python library) reference documentation](https://pdf2image.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html)

Comment: Hi Aakankasha, could you post a representative code snippet to better understand what you are importing into your script and how you are invoking your procedure?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MichaelS added the code. Let me know if it helps